# difference between 2 dates in days, hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: oracle, function, datetime, intervals

I have a function below, which shows the difference between 2 dates in days, hours, minutes and seconds, which is working fine.

I want to expand the function to include the number of years but I'm unsure how to DECLARE the variable in the function. I know it has to be larger than day(3) to second(0). Is there something like a year(3) to second(0)?

As you can see I get the following error when the DATE spans years. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE  OR REPLACE FUNCTION datediff (p_from date, p_to date)
return varchar2 is
  l_interval interval day(3) to second(0);
begin
  l_interval := cast(p_to as timestamp) - cast(p_from as timestamp);
  return extract (day from l_interval) || ' Days '
    || extract (hour from l_interval) || ' Hours '
    || extract (minute from l_interval) || ' Minutes '
    || extract (second from l_interval) || ' Seconds';
end datediff;
/

SELECT 
datediff( TO_DATE('2022-04-01 10:11:13','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
TO_DATE('2022-04-03 17:48:09','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) as  diff FROM DUAL;

DIFF
2 Days 7 Hours 36 Minutes 56 Seconds


SELECT 
datediff( TO_DATE('1981-04-01 10:11:13','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
TO_DATE('2022-04-03 17:48:09','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) as  diff FROM DUAL;

ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small
```

Comment: The simple answer is "the concept doesn't make sense". What is the real-life, practical need for this? See my comments below the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something like a `year(3) to second(0)`?

It does not make sense to have a generic `INTERVAL` data type that contains years, days, hours, minutes and seconds.

If you have an interval of 365 days then if your interval starts on 2022-01-01 than that equals 1 year but if the interval starts on 2020-01-01 then is less than one year as there are 366 days in 2020 due to it being a leap year. Therefore, the number of days in a year depends on which year you are talking about and you cannot have a generic interval that combines days with either months or years as it does not make sense as you need a specific start date.

---

If the date spans years then you could edit your function and increase the leading precision of the `INTERVAL` to `interval day(5) to second(0)` which will let you store about 273 years and then your function will work for your sample data.

```sql
SELECT datediff( TIMESTAMP '1981-04-01 10:11:13', TIMESTAMP '2022-04-03 17:48:09')
         as diff
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DIFF |
> | --- |
> | 14977 Days 7 Hours 36 Minutes 56 Seconds |

---

However, since you have known start- and end-dates then you can find the number of full years between the two bounds and then use an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type calculate the number of days, hours, minutes and seconds on the part-year remainder:

```sql
CREATE  OR REPLACE FUNCTION datediff (p_from date, p_to date)
return varchar2 is
  l_years    PLS_INTEGER;
  l_from     DATE;
  l_interval interval day(3) to second(0);
begin
  l_years := TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(p_to, p_from)/12);
  l_from := ADD_MONTHS(p_from, l_years * 12);
  l_interval := (p_to - l_from) DAY(3) TO SECOND(0);
  return l_years || ' Years '
    || extract (day from l_interval) || ' Days '
    || extract (hour from l_interval) || ' Hours '
    || extract (minute from l_interval) || ' Minutes '
    || extract (second from l_interval) || ' Seconds';
end datediff;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT datediff( TIMESTAMP '2022-04-01 10:11:13', TIMESTAMP '2022-04-03 17:48:09')
         as diff
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DIFF |
> | --- |
> | 0 Years 2 Days 7 Hours 36 Minutes 56 Seconds |

and:

```sql
SELECT datediff( TIMESTAMP '1981-04-01 10:11:13', TIMESTAMP '2022-04-03 17:48:09')
         as diff
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DIFF |
> | --- |
> | 41 Years 2 Days 7 Hours 36 Minutes 56 Seconds |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3dda8ee0bdcea67dd19d7b49776c3cca)*

Comment: A funny thing happens if you change the date portion in your test (keep the time-of-day unchanged) to `2022-02-28` and `2024-02-28` respectively. Notice specifically that the end date is 28 Feb in a **leap** year. Incidentally, what **should** be the "correct" or "expected" or "needed" answer in this case? Then - another funny thing happens if we keep the second timestamp as in your test, and we change the date portion of the first timestamp to either `2020-02-28` or `2020-02-29`; they will both give the same result. Does the OP understand this?